# Minimalistic Linux NTP configuration for broadcast server and broadcast client

Tags: linux, ntp, ntpd

I would like to have a minimalistic NTP configuration setup for multiple Linux computers that are completely isolated from the Internet, sitting on the same network, which synchronise their clock to one machine.

I would like to use NTP broadcast to push time information from the master machine to the clients.

Could someone give me a sample on the bare minimum configuration on how to achieve this? Unfortunately, the documentations do not seem to describe this topic in great detail.

Up until now, I have the following setting for the clients:

```
logfile /var/log/ntp
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift/ntp.drift

keys /etc/ntp.keys
trustedkey 1
requestkey 1
controlkey 1

tinker panic 0
tos orphan 10

broadcastclient
```

And the following for my broadcasting time server:

```
logfile /var/log/ntp
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift/ntp.drift

keys /etc/ntp.keys
trustedkey 1
requestkey 1
controlkey 1

tinker panic 0
tos orphan 10

broadcastclient

server  127.127.1.0     # local clock
fudge   127.127.1.0 stratum 10

broadcast 255.255.255.255
```

I am wondering if I have any issue in my existing configuration.

Comment: So is that working for you? If not, how?

Comment: When I do "ntpq -p" on the NTP client machine I see no indication of any broadcast (refid ".BCST.") while the server machine shows that.

Comment: Limited broadcast (255.255.255.255) is not supported in the current versions of ntp. You will probably need to configure multicast or use the client/server mode and configure the clients via DHCP or DNS.